# Shift of block in menu jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need create timer for submenu in menu. For example after mouse over show it for 3 sec. So I started with function of displaying and hidding submenu. But after first mouse over all works fine,but after second the submenu block shift to next part of menu.

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu_ul > li").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("ul").css("display","block");
    },function(){
    $(this).find("ul").css("display","none");
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="menu_ul">
    <li><a href="#" class="menu_active">Úvod</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Naše škola</a>
        <ul>
            <div>
                <li><a href="#">Školní řád</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Školní knihovna</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="menu_border"> 
                <li><a href="#">Školní hřiště</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dokumenty ke stažení</a></li>     
            </div>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Aktuální školní rok</a></li>
</ul>
```

live ex. http://jsfiddle.net/zg8n2/

Comment: You mean that the `ul` should be visible for 3 sec after the mouse is not longer hovering over the `li`?

Comment: ul of submenu show for 3 sec. because between menu and submenu is empty space. and I can't hover to the submenu without disappearance.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need **[only this](http://jsfiddle.net/zg8n2/5/)** (**No jQuery needed**):

```
.menu_ul > li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
    top:-3px;
}
```

As you can see I've fixed the gap setting the top value to **-3px**, or (thanks to @luke) just lower the `margin-top: 15px` to ... 12 or 13

Additionally you **cannot have** a `DIV` **as a children element of** `UL`. UL can only have `LI`.
**So fix that:** style properly the inner UL elements DIV-alike, use 2 LI elements and inside put again `UL LI` elements to get the 2 columns needed (or something like that, you get the point).

Comment: there is this margin-top:15px. to lower this would be nicer than top:-3px

Comment: @Luke anything just to remove the space-gap. So my answer is: `1.` remove gap at any cost (or set a transparent border-top) `2.` No jQuery needed

Comment: i have nothing against 2) :) gave the +1 for that.

Comment: but I need that empty space. In second step I'll create a small triangle into this space.

Comment: @user3671862 you don't get the point? There's a bunch of tricks to have a space but at the same time being hovering that element... I gave you one example. Is there something unclear?

Answer (score 0):

You are using invalid html which can cause unusual or unexpected behavior.

`<div>` is not a valid child of `<ul>` nor a valid parent of `<li>`. Using proper valid markup should help

Comment: hm, you right, did not see it... does it fix the issue?

Comment: but with <div> element I split up the submenu to two parts.

Comment: @user3671862 really doesn't matter why you did it. It is completely invalid and different browsers will do different things with invalid code

Comment: sorry if i ask, but if you are not answering to fixing the issue, you might want to move your statement into comments?